# Security and Permissions

Tags: security, permissions

I came across a strange situation with `SDL Tridion 2011 SP1`. I have a user (non-administrator). This user has only `Folder Management` on a given publication. When I try to create a new component as this user, I do not see the option to create a new component. I cannot even copy/paste a component which is the expected behaviour.

However if I copy/paste a folder containing components, the cloned folder also contains a copy of the components from the original folder and I can't delete these cloned components since the user does have `Component Management` rights.

To my understanding if the user does not have `Component Management` rights then they should not be able to clone components as well.

I am able to reproduce the same behaviour with SDL Tridion 2013 as well.

Please advice.

Comment: Sounds like you should be opening a ticket with support...

Comment: Thanks Nuno. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious.

Comment: I think this is intentional. You are copying the Folder, with everything in it.

Comment: Hi hzahid, with "Folder Management" permissions, are you able to see the folder contents? I mean the building blocks within the folder.

Comment: @JaimeSantosAlcón Yes with `Folder Management` I am able to see the contents of the folder including `Components` in it.

Comment: @PeterKjaer I think without `Component Management` rights a user should not be able to copy/paste `Components`. During this test I accidentally copied a number of `Components` as a side-effect of copy/pasting `Folders` and now I can not delete those unwanted `Components`.  A typical use-case would be Editors who are responsible for managing `Mailings` and/or `Distribution Lists` need `Folder Management` rights but I do not want them to create any `Components` in a specific `Publication` where they should only be managing `Mailings` and/or `Distribution Lists`.

Comment: You aren't allowed to copy/paste Components - but you ARE allowed to copy/paste Folders, which will copy everything underneath them. If it didn't, you can imagine how many issues that would lead to as well (e.g. "why aren't my templates being copied!"). I understand that's not what you want in this case, but I'm pretty sure it's intentional. For your example, note that there's an OE Folder Management right specifically (but the copy of those folders works the same way). I'd say Folder Management rights are meant to be combined with other rights.

Comment: In terms of Tridion `permissions` we just have read, write, delete, and localize. `Folder management` is a `Right`. You might be able to avoid letting a user copy components by removing `read` on the folder the user is trying to copy. The copy might just fail instead, but the user could still change the setting.

Comment: To @PeterKjaer's point, the Default Groups do include a `Information Designer`, which has Folder and other organizational item mangement rights along with Schema Management Rights. Maybe Folder copy shouldn't include Components for users without Component Management rights, but that needs to be submitted to Support or on SDL Tridion Ideas as a request.

Comment: Follow-up on permissions: to be sure I tried removing `read` on a folder and though another user without the permission can not *see* (based on the MMC Snap-in setting) the items, the user can still copy the folder with content intact. Regardless, the user would still be able to change the setting in Folder permissions.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is by design. The various rights act directly on the item types they are named for. The behaviour you have seen is a bit strange, but that is caused by configuring a strange combination of rights. Usually you have `Folder Management` and `Component Management` together - the people who work with components need to be able to manipulate folders too.